# ERROR while using mapply: "length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent "

Tags: r, mapply

In R, when I attempt to use mapply with the listed formula on the following data, I get a dimnames error. I've looked at other responses with this dimnames error but haven't found any useful solutions. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
organizations <- data.frame(
  orgs = c("org1","org2","org,3"), 
  num_count = c(8,4,2), 
  position = c("position1", "position2", "position1"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  )

students <- data.frame(
  first_choice = c("org1", "org3", "org2", "org2"),
  role = c("position1", "position1", "position2", "position2"),
  id = c(2, 3, 9, 4),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  )


choice<-function(x,y,z){
  ifelse(z<=subset(organizations, orgs==x & position==y, num_count), x  , "2nd Choice")
}
students$org <-mapply(choice,Students$first_choice,atudents$role,atudents$id)
```

The error looks like:

> ```
>  Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
>   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
> ```

.

Answer (score 0):

The error is based on a `,` in `"org,3"` in the 'organizations' data resulting in the non-matching by using `==`. i.e. if we look below

```
Map(function(x, y, z) subset(organizations, Orgs == x& position == y, 
           num_count),Students$first_choice,Students$role,Students$id)
#$org1
#  num_count
#1         8

#$org3
#[1] num_count
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)  #### no match

#$org2
#  num_count
#2         4

#$org2
#  num_count
#2         4
```

Once it is corrected, it would work fine

```
Students$org<- mapply(choice,Students$first_choice,Students$role,Students$id)
Students$org
#[1] "org1"       "2nd Choice" "2nd Choice" "org2"
```

---

Other option is

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f= choice, unname(Students))))
```

#### Update

Based on the OP' clarification, if there are non-matches, then we need to have a condition to make sure that it returns `FALSE`

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y, z) {
      x1 <- subset(organizations, Orgs == x& position == y, num_count)[,1]
    if(length(x1) > 0 && z <= x1) x else "2nd Choice"
    },
    Students$first_choice,Students$role,Students$id))
```

Comment: Drat! The unwanted comma error wasn't in the original data but had the same dimnames error there.

Comment: @JoelMoore  It happens when there is no match.  You need to have a condition to get FALSE there.

Comment: @JoelMoore  Updated the post

Comment: My thanks, I'll try to work through that and update.

Comment: Awesome! Found the glitch in the original code. Thank you so much, @akrun.